# How to remove Windows credentials

Tags: c#, credentials

Using the following command, all stored Windows credentials will be shown.

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr
```

I'm looking for a way to remove a single credential, e.g. credentials to a special server.

The C# Windows application shall remove the credential.
I was looking into the namespaces **System.Web.Security** and **System.ServiceModel.Security**, but that seems not to fit.

I guess there should be a managed Windows API that can do the job.

How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry Ron, but maybe I don't get the point and look into the wrong direction.

Comment: Does this help? https://security.stackexchange.com/a/110742 e.g. `cmdkey /delete`

Comment: Thanks, but that is my last Option. I would prefer a native C# API call, instead of calling a command ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CredentialManagement/. It can get, set, and remove Windows credentials.

Actually, there isn't any official C# API. This NuGet package just wraps the necessary DLL file calls.

Comment: Thx. I'll give it a try.

Comment: unfortunatly I had no time, but will try as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

This part of the Windows libraries is currently **not wide-open** for the world. The reason behind is simple: We are working with *credentials*, once we load them into .NET environment, they would became immediately handled by managed code and easy to access (steal).

Based on that, Microsoft have prepared program **cmdkey** (as [mentioned](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/110742/131820) by itsme86 in comments).

> The **cmdkey.exe** is a *Credential Manager Command Line Utility*.
>
> This file is part of Microsoft® Windows® Operating System. Cmdkey.exe is developed by Microsoft Corporation. It’s a system and hidden file. Cmdkey.exe is usually located in the %SYSTEM% sub-folder and its usual size is 13,824 bytes.

---

If you want to use it in the C#, there is a need to create own API around (or use existing one if there is some). For list of the targets you can do following:

```
const string cSplitString = "target="; // word "target" might differ in other languages

var targets = new List<string>();
var proc = new Process // We need separate process to get the output
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmdkey.exe",
        Arguments = "/list",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
proc.Start();

// reading output from the process
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    if (line.Contains(cSplitString))
        targets.Add(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(cSplitString)+cSplitString.Length));
}
```

And for deleting:

```
string deleteTarget = "test";
Process.Start("cmdkey.exe", "/delete:" + targets.First(a => a.Contains(deleteTarget)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it's really working.

```
Install-Package CredentialManagement -Version 1.0.2
    or
    dotnet add package CredentialManagement --version 1.0.2
```

It will be useful. You can download it from [this link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CredentialManagement/).